# Click event lost when DOM is modified

Tags: javascript, html

There are two `input` elements which hide themselves on blur. The problem is that the click event which caused the blur is lost if the click was on an element which comes after the element being hidden in the DOM.

If the clicked element is *before* the blurred element, it works as expected

This simple snippet demonstrates:

```
<html>
<script src="./jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').blur(function(e) {
            console.log('blurred');
            $(this).hide();
        });

        $('.a').click(function() {
            console.log('div clicked');
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            console.log('doc clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<div class="a"><input /></div>
<div class="a"><input /></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the bottom input is clicked, then the top, it works as expected - "blurred" prints, then "div clicked", then "doc clicked" and the bottom input is hidden.

If the top input is clicked, then the bottom, the top input is hidden, only "blurred" prints and the click event can't be handled anywhere.

If the call to `hide` is commented out, it also works as expected.

Using `.live` doesn't make a difference.

I can think of ways to work around this, but none are very good. Any thoughts on why the order of the `input`s matters, or better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, fixed, but doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @RobG that depends on his doctype. XHTML have closing tags for inputs <input /> HTML doctype do not.

Comment: It doesn't matter - thanks for replying, any thoughts on the event-handling aspect of the question?

Comment: How is the DOM modified?

Comment: By hiding the `input`. I suppose that doesn't actually count as modifying the DOM, originally I was removing the `input`.

Comment: Ok, are you experiencing the same problem with this demo http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/nwaBW/ ? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, using up to date Chrome on OS X

Comment: I can´t recreate your problem using Chrome on Win 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK OK OK this is just us collectively being stupid together.

Look what is happening when you are clicking from top to bottom.

Top  has focus. When you click into the 2nd input THAT IS UNDERNEATH IT, the blur event fires *before* the click event registers on the 2nd div.

What's happening is that you *are* clicking into the 2nd input to give it focus. Since events bubble up from the target that's clicked (the 2nd input), it gets focus. But since the 1st input blur event fires first, it reduces the height of the top div to 0 and that *immediately* moves the 2nd div up beyond the range of the the current mouse position. Therefore, the click event on the 2nd div *never happens*, because the div is already moved out of the way before that happens.

You can see why in this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Z884F/ I've added 
 elements to maintain the div heights even after their inputs are being hidden. If you look at the console, you'll see it works as expected.

The reason Firefox works is that it handles the timing of events a little differently.

IGNORE MY ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW:

This is very strange behavior. I've verified your results in Chrome and Safari on Mac OS 10.7. However, Firefox 12.0 works as expected.

If you do the blur inside a 500ms setTimeout, it works as expected. Though I think the event on the parent div is still being removed.

I have a jsfiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/gsuTw/

I would highly recommend filing this as a bug over at the jQuery dev site. This looks like a bug with blur().

Comment: I don't think it's jquery's problem though. Same behavior occurs if you use javascript's onblur. It's indeed a strange behavior...

Comment: Rob, look at my modified answer above.

Comment: Is that really how it works? I would expect the event to bubble up by parent, not screen position. Also, why would the click event disappear rather than occur on whatever element is below the cursor when the click happens? In that case the event would at least be caught by document.

Comment: I don't agree that its how it works. Seems like Firefox handles this properly. But by making the div have equal height like in the demo, it worked.

Comment: After more experimentation, I think you're pretty much right - the click causes the input to blur, that handler runs, then the click is *recalculated* based on the original screen position of the click. If the originally clicked element is still under that point, all is well. But if it isn't, the click is lost. Even though there is a new element under that position, it will not receive the click. Except in FF. This is strange to me but I guess I'll have to live with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The *srcElement* property of event objects is peculiar to the IE event model. jQuery "normalises" the event object by adding `e.target` where absent but not `e.srcElement`:

```
    // Fix target property, if necessary (#1925, IE 6/7/8 & Safari2)
    if ( !event.target ) {
        event.target = originalEvent.srcElement || document;
    }
```

So in the line:

```
>  $(e.srcElement).hide();
```

'e.srcElement` returns undefined and the statement does nothing.

The fix is to either change `e.srcElement` to `e.target` or use `this` instead.

Note that in the listener, `this` is the element that called the listener, whereas `target` is the element from which the original event was dispatched. Therefore they may or may not reference the same element.

In the blur listeners, `this === event.target`, but not in the click listeners.

BTW, it's considered bad practice to chain calls together because it makes errors (like this one) hard to find and debug. Having a library that silently ignores such errors makes it even harder, consider instead:

```
    $('input').blur(function(e) {

        if (e.srcElement) {
          $(e.srcElement).hide();

        } else {
          // No e.srcElement? what now!!
        }
    });
```

Defensive coding practices are passe for web developers, but they are far more reliable and easier to debug.

Comment: I understand this but it doesn't change the fact that the click handlers are never called.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because the `input`s are always hidden properly. I see that I didn't explain that point of it in the original question, my mistake.

Comment: You edited the original code, changing `e.srcElement` to `this`, as suggested, so of course it now "works".

Comment: Actually there is no change in behavior, in Chrome anyway.

Comment: @RobLourens—that's probably because Chrome supports the IE event model as well as the W3C model, so it has `event.srcElement`. Opera probably supports it too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this gives an answer to why the event got swallowed. But if the position of the input is not a concern, you can change the visibility instead.

```
$('input').blur(function(e) {
    console.log('blurred');
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```